# Continuous color scale legend not updating with radio button options

Tags: python, plotly-dash, jupyterdash

I'm making a quick heatmap view to help track some user activities using jupyter-dash and plotly express. My colorscale legend doesn't update unless data is completely depopulated/repopulated (with checkbox component not included in the minimal example). I've narrowed it down to the radioitems component filtering I use. It's unclear to me if I'm running into an interaction between dash/plotly or if it's the way I approach creating a week/day specific dataframe for plotting.

I've verified it shows up independent of the mode used in app.run_server(), and the same issue appears when using dash.Dash rather than JupyterDash to initialize the app. Here's a minimal reproduction of the issue with all other components removed.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import random
```

```
def week_from_day(years, days):
    assert len(years) == len(days), "The length of years and days series should match."
    weeks = [0]*len(years)
    for i, (year, day) in enumerate(zip(years, days)):
        weeks[i] = datetime.date.isocalendar(datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=int(day-1)))[1]
    return weeks

def date_from_yearday(year_day):
    return (datetime.datetime(year_day[0], 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=int(year_day[1]-1))).date()
```

```
def fake_dashboard_data(users, days):
    data_lists = []
    for user in range(1, users):
        for day in range(70, days+70):
            act_count = random.randint(0,5)
            temp_dict = {'user': user,
                        'year': 2021,
                        'day': day,
                        'field1': random.randint(0,2),
                        'field2': act_count,
                        'field3': random.randint(0,act_count),
                        'field4': random.randint(0,act_count)
                        }
            data_lists.append(temp_dict)
    fake_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_lists)
    fake_df['date'] = fake_df[['year', 'day']].apply(date_from_yearday, axis=1)
    return fake_df

data = fake_dashboard_data(30, 60)
```

```
#Initializations needed for dash app
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='week_or_day',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Weekly', 'value': 'week'},
            {'label': 'Daily', 'value': 'daily'}],
    value='week'),
    dcc.Graph(id='user_summary_figure')])
    
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('user_summary_figure', 'figure'),
    Input('week_or_day', 'value'))
def filter_heatmap(week_or_day):  
    #conditional DF formatting based on radio button
    if week_or_day == 'week':
        #Don't modify original data within callbacks. 
        summary_df = data.copy()
        #Add week field and drop day. 
        summary_df['week'] =week_from_day(summary_df['year'], summary_df['day'])
        summary_df.drop(['day', 'date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        #melt into long form
        summary_df = summary_df.melt(id_vars=['user', 'year', 'week'], var_name='response_type', value_name='count')
        #sort and create a year-week column before returning
        summary_df = summary_df.reset_index().sort_values(['year', 'week', 'user'])
        summary_df.insert(0, 'time_period', summary_df['year'].astype(str) + ' - ' + summary_df['week'].astype(str))
        
        #week plot formatting
        bins_time = summary_df['week'].nunique()
        
    else: #day formatting
        #Don't modify original data within callbacks.
        summary_df = data.copy()
        #melt into long form for plotly
        summary_df = summary_df.melt(id_vars=['user', 'year', 'day', 'date'], var_name='response_type', value_name='count')
        #sort and create a year-day column before returning
        summary_df = summary_df.reset_index().sort_values(['year', 'day', 'user'])
        summary_df.insert(0, 'time_period', summary_df['year'].astype(str) + ' - ' + summary_df['day'].astype(str))
                
        #week plot formatting
        bins_time = summary_df['day'].nunique()
    
    #need user column that cannot be forced to any date type. Dash will force conversion
    summary_df.insert(0, 'user_str', 'user: ' + summary_df['user'].astype(str))
    
    user_summary_fig = px.density_heatmap(summary_df,
                        x='time_period', 
                        y='user_str', 
                        z='count',
                        nbinsx=bins_time,
                        histfunc='sum', 
                        color_continuous_scale='RdYlGn')
    return user_summary_fig
```

```
app.run_server(mode='inline', debug=False)
```

Comment: One interesting note is that when the checkbox component is in the app with the radiobutton, my legend will not update the colorscale when individual boxes are checked/unchecked. Prior to the addition of the radiobutton, that action had a legend update.

Answer (score 2):

Tried a number of different things. The filtering issues were ultimately unrelated to which filtering component was being used. Dropdowns, date selectors and checkboxes all had the same issues.

resolving it was as easy as adding an update_traces call as the last step of the callback, specifying the colorscale.

```
fig.update_traces(dict(colorscale='Tealrose_r', coloraxis=None))
```